# solving second order differential equation by numercial method

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

i have this differential equation and i don't know how to solve it via numerical methods.

$\ (y'')^2 - 100y' -1000y^3= 3t^2  $

($y$ is a function of $t$ and $t$ is the time)

my professor wrote this following stuff for us, to solve this differential equation with them.

$\frac {dy}{dt} = \frac {y(t)-y(t-\Delta t)}{\Delta t}$

$\frac {dy}{dt} = \frac {y(t+\Delta t)-y(t)}{\Delta t}$

$\frac {dy}{dt} = \frac {y(t+\Delta t)-y(t-\Delta t)}{2\Delta t}$

$\frac {d^2y}{dt^2} = \frac {y(t+\Delta t)-2y(t)+y(t-\Delta t)}{\Delta t^2}$

i should solve this at $t=0.25 $ ( the $\Delta t$ must be taken $0.05$)

he said we should draw tables and go forward step by step from $t=0$  to $t=0.25$ by taking $\Delta t =0.05$ .

you can choose initial values whatever you want.
( $y$ and $y'$ can be $0$ at $t=0$.)

Comment: Is it $(y'')^2$ or $y''$?

Comment: without initial values?

Comment: As @Raffaele suggested, you need $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$

Comment: i edited it. @Moo

Comment: @Andrei yes we can take $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=0$.

Comment: Use those equations to write $y(t+\Delta_t)$ as a function of $y(t)$ and $y(t-\Delta_t)$. Choose $y(0)$ and $y(\Delta_t)$. Then repeatedly solve for $y(2 \Delta_t)$, $y(3\Delta_t)$, etc...

Comment: @Wouter the problem is i don't have the value of $y(0.05)$ or $y(\Delta t)$. so i can't go any further steps. besides, the $y(t-\Delta t)$ doesn't mean at $t=0$ because $t$ is time and it can't be negative.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the leading derivative occurs non-linearly? What is the context of this exercise, were Clairaut or other implicit ODE mentioned?

Comment: @LutzL it has no context. my professor said solve this second-order differential equation with numeric methods.unfortunately it is what it is.

Comment: @Dawsh If you can choose your initial values ($y$ and $y'$) whatever you want at $t=0$, that means you can choose $y(0)$ and $y(\Delta_t)$ whatever you want. If $y(-\Delta_t)$ bothers you, just time-shift your equations until that no longer occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the first equation, you can write that $y(-\Delta t)=0$. From your conditions, $y''(0)=0$ as well. Now use the formulas to get an expression for $y(\Delta t)$.
$$y''(0)=\frac{y(\Delta t)}{\Delta t^2}\\
y'(0)=\frac{y(\Delta t)}{2\Delta t}$$ so you get an equation for $y(\Delta t)$. Once you solve it, you can calculate $y'(\Delta t)$. You rewrite your equations in terms of $y(2\Delta t)$. Try to solve that. And so on

Comment: if $y''(0)=0$ , then $y''(0) = \frac{y(\Delta t)}{\Delta t^2} $ must be 0 too, then $y(\Delta t)$ would be 0 and we can't go any further. besides, is it possible to speak of $y(-\Delta t)$ when t is the time and it can't be negative?

Comment: Remember that these are just approximations. I should have said $y''\approx 0$. And why can't time be negative? You set your origin somewhere in time, anything that happened before it's a negative time. I just need one step, to be able to calculate the next one

Comment: just one more thing, if we have the initial value of $y''(0)=0$ , then how $y''(0)=\frac{y(\Delta t)}{\Delta t^2}$ is not exactly equal to $0$? you said it is just approximation. but if we have initial value of $y''$, it should be exactly $0$, shouldn't it?